# Searching cells and columns for specific values when cells contain multiple values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wanting to count the frequency of a specific value within a column even if there are multiple values within the same cell. I have tried the `COUNTIF` function, however, when cells contain multiple values, it does not count them.

For example:

```
-
Alu
-
Alu, PC
-
PC
-
PC, Alu
-
```

When I perform the `COUNTIF` function on this example dataset, the frequency of `Alu` is `1` when it is desirable for the output to be `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the string you are searching for. I.e. `=COUNTIF(A1:A9;"*alu*")` will give the result you are looking for.

[image]